# Allow the end-user to switch the Entity Framework provider at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Consider that I have configured EF with a .NET Core web app:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => 
    options.UseSqlServer(...));
```

I can also download a package to support for example SQLite:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlite(...));
```

How can we allow a user to "select" the provider on app install? I mean - for example, in WordPress you can choose from a dropdown.

Is this possible in .NET Core? The only way I see is to restart the app only...

Comment: What's the use case? Seems pretty much pointless from my point of view. For a CMS or Blog you never "just" change the database type without taking the application down / restarting

Comment: Yep - but while "first install" you can choose db provider.
I'd like to allow client to decide which provider to use - without modifying source code.

Comment: Well, while technically possible to edit the project.json from within the application then restart the app, I don't think it's a very wise from an security perspective. In wordpress the installation scripts are deleted afterwards, that's way harder in a compiled system and leaving it there opens up security issues. Of course no one is forcing you to use `AddDbContext` in startup and resolve your DB Context via an abstract factory which reads a configuration value and choose the right provider and constructs it manually, but then you'll need to manage its lifetime yourself (i.e. disposing it)

Comment: Why do you use teh same db context ? You can have two db context with the same db sets properties and use according a selected option by user

Comment: Thanks for comments! Two DB context seems reasonable, but I'm curious what happens when two providers are configured. In connection string in web.config the provider type can be specified, but I am not sure about appsettings.json.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example on how you can implement a `DbContextFactory` or a `DbContextProxy<T>` which will create the correct provider and return it.

```
public interface IDbContextFactory
{
    ApplicationContext Create();
}

public class DbContextFactory() : IDbContextFactory, IDisposable
{
    private ApplicationContext context;
    private bool disposing;

    public DbContextFactory()
    {
    }

    public ApplicationContext Create() 
    {
        if(this.context==null) 
        {
            // Get this value from some configuration
            string providerType = ...;
            // and the connection string for the database
            string connectionString = ...;

            var dbContextBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder();
            if(providerType == "MSSQL") 
            {
                dbContextBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
            }
            else if(providerType == "Sqlite")
            {
                dbContextBuilder.UseSqlite(connectionString);
            }
            else 
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid providerType");
            }

            this.context = new ApplicationContext(dbContextBuilder);
        }

        return this.context;
    }

    public void Dispose(){
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing){
        if (disposing){
            disposing?.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Also make sure you implement the disposable pattern as show above, so the context gets disposed as soon as the factory gets disposed, to prevent the DbContext remaining in memory longer than necessary and free unmanaged resources as soon as possible.

Finally register the factory as scoped, as you would the context itself:

```
services.AddScopedd<IDbContextFactory, DbContextFactory>();
```

A more advanced and generic/extendable approach is by creating a `IDbContextProxy<T>` class which uses a bit of reflection to get the correct constructor and the `DbContextOptionsBuilder` to it.

Also possible to create a `IDbContextBuilder` which abstracts the provider creation.

```
public class SqlServerDbContextBuilder IDbContextBuilder
{
    public bool CanHandle(string providerType) => providerType == "SqlServer";

    public T CreateDbContext<T>(connectionString)
    {
        T context = ... // Create the context here

        return context;
    }
}
```

Then you can pick the correct provider w/o a hard coded `if/else` or `switch` block just by doing

```
// Inject "IEnumerable<IDbContextBuilder> builders" via constructor
var providerType = "SqlServer";
var builder = builders.Where(builder => builder.CanHandle(providerType)).First();
var context = builder.CreateDbContext<ApplicationContext>(connectionString);
```

and adding new types of provider is as easy as adding the dependencies and an `XxxDbContextBuilder` class.

See [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/01/10/RoleInterfaceRoleHint/), [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/01/11/PartialTypeNameRoleHint/) or [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2013/01/09/MetadataRoleHint/) for more information about this and similar approaches.

Comment: Thanks, this look nice!

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use repositories which are using a db context you specified and you can pass a parameter to context constructor to choose the endpoint. I am not sure on this but it might work for your situation.

I followed this article for repository pattern, I recommend to read it :)

http://cpratt.co/generic-entity-base-class/